# Recursive rm with condition in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I have the following folder structure:

```
parent
 - folder1
   - main1.x
   - main1.y
   - main1.z
   - main1-626262.x
   - main1-626263.x
   - main1-626264.x
   - main1-626265.x
   - main1-626266.x
   - main1-626267.x
 - folder2
   - main2.x
   - main2.y
   - main2.z
   - main2-726262.x
   - main2-726263.x
   - main2-726264.x
   - main2-726265.x
   - main2-726266.x
   - main2-726267.x
```

Now, I want to remove: `main-*********.x`

So, my required folder structure:

```
parent
 - folder1
   - main1.x
   - main1.y
   - main1.z
 - folder2
   - main2.x
   - main2.y
   - main2.z
```

So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
find * -name 'main?-*.x' | xargs echo rm -rf
```

The above prints a command that removes the unwanted directories (*without* actually removing them). If it looks OK, simply run the printed command, or run

```
find * -name 'main?-*.x' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: `main-` is not consistent. It's name depends on the name of actual `main.x`

Comment: Then please modify the `-name` option to suit your needs. You can use the wildcards such as `?` and `*`. You can even use `grep` in between `find` and `xargs` to filter the directories to be removed.

Comment: I will give it a shot and update the question. Thanks

Comment: Do not use the -r if you dont need it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple command:

```
rm `find ./ -name 'main?-*.x'` -rf
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
rm */*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*
```

But needs a bash or sh to evaluate. Don't know about C-Shell, if it doesn't work some similar syntax will be available.